# does small different between 16s ribosomal DNA leads to diffrence into protein products?

Tags: molecular-biology

I have bacterium isolate after BLAST of its 16S  the different between its and the similar seq. on NCBI was 4 nucleotides my question is, does it lead to difference between whole genome seq. or I will obtain the same seq. consequently. does this also leads to  the same protein products from them.

Answer (score 1):

The 16s ribosomal DNA does not code for any protein, it codes for the [16s ribosmal RNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16S_ribosomal_RNA), which is part of the (small subunit of the) [ribosome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosome).

The differences will most likely not affect the ribosome much, but to be sure you'd have to check the exact position of the mutations in a reference structure and see if they are at important positions (i.e. binding of the Shine-Dalgarno sequence)